# Utilizando GFix em uma aplicação C#

Tags: c#, firebird

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# e necessito passar o GFix em um banco de dados FireBird, pensei em executar uma janela do prompt e passar os comandos do GFix para ela, porem não estou conseguindo. Alem disso eu preciso retornar uma mensagem pro usuário se o banco estiver ok ou corrompido, não se como fazer isso também. 
Obrigado desde já, espero que tenham entendido.

Answer (score 1):

Este exemplo demonstra como, a partir do C#, executar um programa / aplicativo externo e ler a saída ou os resultados deste programa.

O código abaixo dispara o prompt de comando do Windows (`cmd.exe`) e passa para ele o comando que deve ser executado (no caso, o comando `dir`).

Na propriedade `Arguments` você pode substituir o comando *dir* pelo aplicativo do seu interesse (GFix com seus respectivos parâmetros).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class RedirectingProcessOutput
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c dir *.cs";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("Output:");
        Console.WriteLine(output);    
    }
}
```

Este código foi copiado do [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878632/best-way-to-call-external-program-in-c-sharp-and-parse-output/878660#878660).